# Python: putting lists from a file into a list

Tags: python, list, file

i'm very begginer in python.

i have a file with lists of coordinates. it seems like that :

```
[-122.661927,45.551161], [-98.51377733,29.655474], [-84.38042879, 33.83919567].
```

i'm trying to put this into a list with:

```
with open('file.txt', 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        list.append(line)
```

the result i got is

```
['[-122.661927,45.551161], [-98.51377733,29.655474], [-84.38042879, 33.83919567]']
```

could sombody help me how can i get rid of the "'" marks at the beggining and the end of the list?

Comment: The way you put here, you actually have only one line. You have to improve you code to manipulate the string and break the contents into lines.

Comment: sorry i pasted it worng way, it is in lines in the file

Answer (score 3):

Try using `ast.literal_eval`.

Example -

```
import ast
lst = []
with open('file.txt', 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        lst.extend(ast.literal_eval(line))
```

From documentation -

> **ast.literal_eval(node_or_string)**
>
> Safely evaluate an expression node or a Unicode or Latin-1 encoded string containing a Python literal or container display. The string or node provided may only consist of the following Python literal structures: strings, numbers, tuples, lists, dicts, booleans, and None.

Also, please note its bad to use `list` as a variable name, as it shadows the `list` built-in function.

Comment: thanks, i tried and got an error:     raise ValueError('malformed node or string: ' + repr(node))
ValueError: malformed node or string: <_ast.Subscript object at 0x0310EE50> the list name was just for example so it was clear it's a list, it has a different name in real:)

Comment: can you print `line` and tell what the result is?

Comment: @KasiaSawicka if the input is like you gave in the question, this should work. If its not working, could you please update what the `line` looks like for which it is not working?

Comment: it's: [-122.661927,45.551161], [-98.51377733,29.655474], [-84.38042879, 33.83919567]

Comment: This should work, are you sure, you are using the exact code i gave?

Comment: yes, i retried it and had the same error... anyway i got the solution from inspectorG4dget work:) so will use that one. thanks for your help in any case:)

Answer (score 0):

Use `ast.literal_eval` to convert the string list to list objects,also you can use a list comprehension to loop over your file object that is more faster than python loops and directly returns a list:

```
import ast
with open('file.txt', 'r') as f:
     my_list=[ast.literal_eval(line) for line in f]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
answer = []
with open('file.txt') as infile:
    for line in infile:
        line = line.strip().rstrip('.').replace('[', ' ').replace(']', ' ').replace(',', ' ')
        parts = map(float, line.split())
        answer.extend(zip(parts, parts))
```

Ouput:

```
In [83]: answer
Out[83]: 
[(-122.661927, 45.551161),
 (-98.51377733, 29.655474),
 (-84.38042879, 33.83919567)]
```

Comment: thanks but i'd like to get rid of the " ' " marks and have sth like that [[-122.661927,45.551161], [-98.51377733,29.655474], [-84.38042879, 33.83919567]]

Comment: @KasiaSawicka: Ack! I forgot to do something. Check out the edit!